# Pyspark module not found error even after passing module as zip file

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, python-module

I have a Pyspark code repo which i am sending to the spark session as a zip file through --pyFile parameter. I am doing this because there is a UDF defined in one of the python files within the module which is not available when we run the code as the module is not available in the workers.

Even though all the python files are present inside the zip file i still get the module not found error.

|-Module 
|----test1.py 
|----test2.py 
|----test3.py

When i try to `from Module.test2 import foo` to import in test3.py i get an error that module.test2 is not found. test2 contains an pyspark UDF.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

#### Initiate a spark session

```
spark = SparkSession.builder\
                        .appName(self.app_name)\
                        .master(self.master)\
                        .config(conf=conf)\
                        .getOrCreate()
```

- Remove the config - if not needed.

#### Make sure that the Module.zip is in the same directory as main.py

```
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("Module.zip")
```

#### Dependency imports after adding the package.zip path to SparkSession.

```
from Module.test2 import foo
```

#### Finally

|-main.py      - Core code to be executed. 
|-Module.zip   - Dependency module zipped.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder\
                    .appName(self.app_name)\
                    .master(self.master)\
                    .config(conf=conf)\
                    .getOrCreate()

spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("Module.zip")

from Module.test2 import foo
```

> IMPORTANT - Make sure you correctly zip you file - if the problem persists try other zip methods.